# using wkhtmltopdf in Tiki on Windows

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, tiki-wiki

I have installed a Tiki 9.2 on a Windows XP machine running Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.17. I have installed wkhtmltopdf under the program files folder (C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf). I have entered the path in the $PATH variable. However, it seems no matter what path I enter in the Tiki config interface, it does not call the executable. I have checked the executable works using the command line.

I have tried backslashes, forward slashes, double quotes, double quotes x2, %20 in space with the file/// at the front. Nothing calls it from the interface.

Anyone had this?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess: Try C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe or simply wkhtmltopdf.exe if you have it in $PATH (not sure if the executable is named wkhtmltopdf.exe - please double check).